# how to run onEdit funtion with a button

Tags: google-apps-script

my onEdit function does not work when there is frequent disconnection of internet.
i want to assign it to a button so that when there is internet available i will press the button and does it work.
i also tried change the function name but still does not perform its work with a button. how ever it works without button the code is

```
function onEdit(evt) {
try {
if( evt.range.getSheet().getName() === "invoice" ) {
  // Qty is in column F
  if( ( evt.range.getRow() > 7 ) && ( evt.range.getRow() < 29 ) && ( 
evt.range.getColumn() === 6 ) ) {
    var sheet = evt.source.getSheetByName("stock");
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
    var stock = range.getValues();
    for( var i=0; i<stock.length; i++ ) {
      // Compare to column B
      if( stock[i][0] === evt.range.offset(0,-4,1,1).getValue() ) {
        range.offset(i,2,1,1).setValue(evt.value);
        return
      }
    }
        //this alert no need if this function assigned to a button
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Item 
<"+evt.range.offset(0,-4,1,1).getValue()+"> not found!");
  }
 }
 }
catch(err) {
Logger.log(err);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addmenuname-submenus) to manually run your code. In this example, assume that your `onEdit()` function is now called `doSomething()`.

```
// The onOpen function is executed automatically every time a Spreadsheet is loaded
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push({name: "Do Something", functionName: "doSomething"});
  ss.addMenu("Custom Menu", menuEntries);
}
```

You're going to have to rewrite your script so that it does not rely on `evt`, as that will no longer be available.

Comment: your suggestion will work but i have the problem that after loading my spreadsheet. i have internet dis-connectivity some times in minutes. so i want when i get chance internet connection and press the button